# Is there a regedit or something to force my bootcamp Windows 10 to recognize my 2014 MacBook Pro touchpad as a Precision Touchpad?

Tags: windows, mac, touchpad

Is there a regedit or something to force my bootcamp Windows 10 to recognize my 2014 MacBook Pro touchpad as a Precision Touchpad?

I realized it may be a driver thing, but it seems like there should be a simple hack to convince windows the very good touchpad on the newer macbooks is a precision touchpad...  Thus allowing inverse scrolling and the like...

Answer (score 0):

The only 'fix' appears to be [Trackpad++](http://trackpad.powerplan7.com)

Watch out for the junkware it offers to install.

Apparently, it claims to be free, but you have to either keep reinstalling it every week, or donate for a full-time key - so it's actually trialware/shareware.

Source : [3 Tools to Make Your Mac’s Hardware Work Better in Windows with Boot Camp](http://www.howtogeek.com/197485/3-tools-to-make-your-macs-hardware-work-better-in-windows-with-boot-camp/)